# offline map tiles in standalone desktop app

Tags: c#, tiles, geolocation, standalone, desktop-gis

Which mapping API can be used (either in a C# desktop app or as a standalone mapping app) that accesses an offline tile collection and requires only a minimal amount of additional servers / other applications?

We are currently developing a desktop app in C#, which enables the user to do a fuzzy search on a csv and outputs a place name, for which I have generated two columns of lat/long values.

Now we would like to add map functionality with mouseover labels and give location/district/province, next to a table view of the search result (name/district/province). This map can either be implemented as a window in the search app or as another standalone. I know how to generate a collection of tiles and use these in a web app, but I am stuck on how to bring a map window into a desktop app without the need of having to run all sorts of servers. Our users will not be able to get online and as they will not be very IT literate, we are trying to minimise the amount that they need to install (bundled for Windows) or start up before using the app.

I've so far had a look at jxMapViewer (which we probably can't use as we are developing in C#): https://www.java.net//pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use directly brutile: http://brutile.codeplex.com/ or maybe build your app on top of mapsui: http://mapsui.codeplex.com/

Comment: Are you able to expand upon why you think either/both of these may meet the requirements described in the Question?

Comment: take a look at the source code and the sample apps here :http://mapsui.codeplex.com/